# Separate one data frame in two data frames with 70% and 30% of the original content

Tags: r

I would like to separate one dataframe in two using R. As an example, having one dataframe 70% of the original content and the other one having 30%. How could I do that? My dataframe is of size (22740,2).

My dataframe consists in one column having genes and in the other column having the pathway where it belongs. I want to keep that 70-30 relation in EVERY pathway of the dataframe. Therefore, I am not interesting in taking the first 70% rows and do a new dataframe for example.

Hope I explained myself clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, `df2` is the 70%, `df3` is the 30% - `ref` is created to index the entries.  The `group_by` ensures that each pathway is sampled individually.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% mutate(ref=seq_len(nrow(df))) %>% group_by(pathway) %>% sample_frac(0.7)
df3 <- df[-df2$ref,]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random selection of the 30% of the samples, you can do:

```
   # Select a 30% of the samples
     Sel.ID <- sample(1:22740,size = .3*22740,replace=F)
   # The new table with the 30% of the samples would be . . .
     New.Tab.30 <- Tab[Sel.ID,]
   # The table with the 70% of the samples (the remaining) would be . . .
     New.Tab.70 <- Tab[-Sel.ID,]
```

You can run different times, getting different tables. If you want to keep the same, you should use `set.seed(12345)` for example before the first line.

Comment: I think topic starter need `replace = FALSE`

Comment: @GregoryDemin You are right; if not, repeated values can be obtained. Edited in the message